# global sections of a divisor on a cubic surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth cubic hypersurface in $\mathbb P^3$. Then we know that $\text{Pic}(X) \cong \mathbb Z^{7} \cong <L, E_1,.., E_6>$ (can be considered as blow up of $\mathbb P^2$ at $6$ general points).

Is there a way to compute the exact number of independent global section of a divisor of the form, say, $3L-2E_1-E_2-E_3-E_4-E_5-E_6$ using some standard short exact sequence (and the information about the intersection numbers)?

Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think of $H := 3L - \sum E_i$ as the hyperplane class of $X$ (in the embedding as a cubic surface), your linear system identifies with
$$
|H - E_1|,
$$
the linear system of hyperplanes containing the line $E_1 \subset X \subset \mathbb{P}^3$. Now it is obvious that this linear system is a pencil (hence the corresponding line bundle has two independent global sections).

Comment: Thanks. What can be said about other kind of  linear systems say $|2H - E_1-E_2|$? Can we say it is exactly $4$?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.